# Passing funciton into sort in python

Tags: python, sorting

```
def a_func(l1,l2):
    if(abs(l1[0]-l1[1]) > abs(l2[0] - l2[1])):
        return True
    if(abs(l1[0]-l1[1]) == abs(l2[0] - l2[1])):
        if(l1[0] < l2[0]):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return False
```

I want to pass this function as a key argument in `sorted()` function how to do it. when I am passing like this 
`sort(lis,key = a_func)` it is showing error.

Comment: Please also give array input example and expeted output  (by editing your post). A sorter method takes only 1 argument and return a value for it, then each 'value' of each object will be compared, this is not like java where you compare objects 2 by 2

Comment: The `sort` `key` function takes *one* parameter and is supposed to transform it into a value that can be sorted on. It doesn't take two parameters to compare against each other. A sort callback also should never return `True` or `False`, that makes no sense.

Comment: To quote the documentation: "key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each element in iterable (for example, key=str.lower). The default value is None (compare the elements directly).". This does not match that signature.

Comment: You probably want something like `def a_func(l): return abs(l[0] - l[1]), l[0]`, which sorts on the absolute difference between the first and second index and on equality just the first index itself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

Given this function definition/return value:

```
def hand_1_higher_than_hand_2(hand_1, hand_2):
   # Buncha code that changes hand_1/hand_2 to mapped_hand_1/mapped_hand2

   return mapped_hand_1 > mapped_hand_2
```

where hand_1, hand_2, mapped_hand_1, mapped_hands_2 are tuples of 5 ordered pairs

With code that calls this using cmp_to_key in functools:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key
# Stuff....
winners.sort(key=cmp_to_key(hand_1_higher_than_hand_2))
```

could be what you're looking for.

I used this with the max function:

```
    winning_hand = max(winners, key=cmp_to_key(hand_1_higher_than_hand_2))
```

Think it should work the same way with sort functions.